# Euler-Maclaurin-Formula and Finite Size Scaling

Tags: integration, error-analysis, approximations, boundary-terms

I am reading the book "Quantum Inverse Scattering Methode". In this book and in many other papers one looks at finite-size scaling. In this methode one uses often the Euler-MacLaurin-Formular:

$$\sum^b_{i=a} f(i)=\int^{b+\frac{1}{2}}_{a-\frac{1}{2}} f(x) \text{d}x+.....,$$

where the dots incorporate only higher derivative terms of $f$.

I want to understand, how this is related to the standard Euler-Maclaurin formula:

$$ \sum^b_{i=a} f(i)=\int^{b}_{a} f(x) \text{d}x + \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}+.....,$$

where again the dots incorporate higher derivatives. Maybe, it is obvious and I just do not see, how the change in the integration boundaries perfectly cancels the zeroth order correction.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's just Liebnitz version of the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$
\frac{d}{db} \int_{a}^b f(x)dx = f(b)?
$$